# eclipse mosquitto - Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet

Tags: mosquitto

Testing out Eclipse Mosquitto (2.0.14)

mosquitto.conf

```
listener 8883
allow_anonymous true
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    ports:
      - 8883:8883
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
      - ./data:/mosquitto/data
```

Testing like this (from inside the container):

```
mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8883  -m "test" -t test
```

results in

```
Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to the broker from outside the container, I assume something to do with the way the broker binds to the ip address causes this not to work from inside the container (??)

```
mosquitto_pub -h <server> -p 8883  -m "test" -t test
```